# Running logstash script from bin folder and setting java.io.tmpdir

Tags: java, ruby, linux, centos, logstash

I am running Logstash on CentOS 6.7 and I have the issue with /tmp being mounted with no-exec. I have seen that you can use -Djava.tmp.io.tmpdir= but I have been running logstash from the script in the bin folder. Can I still specifiy the jvm arg? I have not been able to figure it out.

I might be really confused, what I would like to do is set the tmp directory for logstash to be something other than /tmp, since it has noexec and will fail. I would like to do this just for logstash. If I run java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir will that affect all my programs running Java?

Answer (score 0):

In the logstash.lib.sh I was able to set JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=